# Symlink does not work for dropbox

Tags: filesystem, backup, dropbox, symbolic-link

I am backing up home folder by create a symlink in dropbox.

What I did:

```
cd ~/Dropbox
mkdir backup && cd backup
ln -s ~
```

What I checked:

1. `ln -l`. The symlink is created.
2. The dropbox folder contains my home folder. However, it only contains the link, rather than the actual file.
3. The web dropbox is empty.

---

This is weird. Almost all articles and Q&A suggest that dropbox would follow the symlink, and sync the folder.

---

I suspect that

1. It is a problem to put home folder under dropbox, because the actual dropbox folder is in home folder.
2. Is there something wrong with the file permission? Most of the file is 644. However, I have no idea why no file end up in the Dropbox cloud.

Comment: Is this a typo? `mkdir backup && cd bakcup`

Answer (score 0):

Of course Dropbox synced only a link, because that is what you put inside a backup directory. But you can do a little trick that should help:

1. Stop dropbox
2. Issue following command:

   sudo mount ~ ~/Dropbox/backup -o bind
3. Start dropbox

The command mounts (binds) your home directory to be also visible under ~/Dropbox/backup path. Then dropbox will see it and synchronize. But be careful not to start dropbox without doing a mount, as it will start to resync with empty directory and you'll end with your home directory copy downloaded

Comment: I did as the instruction goes. However, dropbox only sync symlink, rather than file, again.

Comment: @JohnHass: Do. Not. Create. Symlink. Just stop dropbox (completely, you should quit the application), mount your home directory inside dropbox using `-o bind` parameter and start dropbox again.

Comment: That's a really interesting solution.  But dangerous!  as @nsilent22 says, BE CAREFUL.  The best idea would be to add that bind command to /etc/fstab to make sure it's always mounted before dropbox starts.  Or else one day you will lose everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had to

1. Stop dropbox
2. mv ~/Dropbox /stf/Dropbox
3. ln -s /stf/Dropbox ~ # symlink new location into home folder
4. rm -rf ~/.dropbox ~/.dropbox-dist
5. run dropbox and relink device